# How to store 10 bit float value in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, floating-point, precision, type-conversion

I have a radar device. Various data coming out from device like detected object speed, acceleration distance etc. But the data is in 10 bit and 13 bit float values. How to print that 10 bit and 13 bit float value and how to store that values ? As floats having 32 bit value. I tried to store it in float variable directly but it gives wrong values.

Comment: You will have to know more about the representation than just the total number of bits.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what is needed exactly: exact representation etc...

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more information than that please. Such as a fuller description of the data format, link to the data sheet, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: If you only want to **store** this, `uint16_t` (or `uint8_t[2]` if endianness is an issue) would do the trick. If you need the **value** (interpretation of the bits), you need more info like the width of exponent, significand, their positions, the position of the sign bit, etc.

Comment: And once you know those, use `ldexp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 10-bit case, input consists of:
Bit 15: sign
Bits 10-14: exponent (exponent = (bits 10-14) + 15)
Bits 0-9: signficant   (1.(bits 0-9))

Something like this should work, although note I haven't tested it:

```
int halfFloatToInt16(unsigned int input, int shift)
{

    int exp, output;

    // Load precision: (1.(precision bits 0-9))
    output  = (int)(0x03FF & input);
    output += 0x0400;

    // Apply sign (bit 15)
    output  = (0x8000 & input)?(-output):output;

    // Calculate exponent (bits 10 - 14)
    // Adjustment -25 = -15 for exponent and -10 for significand
    exp  = (int)((0x001F) & (input >> 10));
    exp -= 25;

    // Apply shift to acheive desired fixed point precision
    exp += shift;

    // Shift output
    if(exp > 0)
    {
        return(output << exp);
    }
    else
    {
        return(output >> exp);
    }
}
```

Here the input will be the 16-bit floating point value, as specified above, casted to unsigned int.  The shift identifies the shift that's been applied to the output.  So the output of the function will be the value times two to the power specified by shift.  For example if the expected maximum output value is 1 you would use a shift of 14.  So 16384 represents one.  If the maximum expected value of the output is 20000, you make the shift zero.  This will optimize the overall precision of the output.

Comment: I did not even know that such a type existed:)

Comment: well I'm assuming it's a half-precision number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: How can a 10-bit type have a bit 15? You assume a float16 is meant, but that is not what the question mentions.

Comment: C doesn't really have a data type associated with a 16-bit floating point number, so there isn't really a definition.  I will fix the wording for clarity.

Comment: @JonathonS. In my case maximum expected value for different parameters are 1138.2, 204.8, 127.75 respectively. So what would be the shift values for that parameters. could you please give me the formula ?

Comment: in my case:
parameter 1: 13 bit, -500 to +1138.2 range.
parameter 2: 10 bit, -204 to +204.8 range.
parameter 3: 10 bit, -128 to +127.75 range.

Comment: For the two ten bit cases you could use a shift of 6 since left shifting 204 six times will yield a value of 13056.  For the 13 bit case, you could use a shift of 4 since left shifting 1138.2 four times will yield a value of 18208.  Generally you want to left shift just enough to keep the maximum result less than 32767 minus some buffer so that you won't run into any overflow issues in your code.  Also, keep in mind the example above only covers the ten-bit significand case.